# Make a joined table's rows the field names and values of the main query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Is it possible to make a joined table's rows the field names and values of the main query? 
Let me explain that by showing the structure and data:

```
structs
    id
    type

struct_fields
    id
    struct_id
    name
    value
```

Example data:

```
structs
    1, faq
    2, faq
    3, post

struct_fields
    1, 1, "question", "Will there be food?" 
    2, 1, "answer", "No, you will have to bring your own food"
    3, 1, "active", 1
    4, 2, "question", "Will there be drinks?"
    5, 2, "answer", "Yes, there will be plenty of drinks"
    6, 2, "active", 0
    7, 3, "title", "Great post!"
    8, 3, "body", "Lorum ipsum..."
    9, 3, "published", "2019-01-01 23:12:00"
```

This would give me all structs of type faq, with all corresponding fields

```
SELECT s.*, f.*
FROM `structs` s
RIGHT JOIN `struct_fields` f ON f.struct_id = s.id
WHERE s.type = 'faq'
```

But I have doubles in my rows obviously, because of all the struct_fields that generate rows also

But when I add

```
GROUP BY s.id
```

only the first row of matching struct_fields is shown (phpmyadmin), and with the field names of the struct_fields.

I would love to be able to select all structs, with all the corresponding struct_fields, where the struct_fields name would be the field name in the result and the struct_field value the value, so that I would be able to use HAVING to make a subselection. 
So:

Result:

```
id, type, question,                answer,          active
1,  faq,  "Will there be food?",   "No, you...",    1
2,  faq,  "Will there be drinks?", "Yes, there...", 0
```

So now I would be able to extend the query with things like:

in case of faq e.g.: `HAVING active = 1 (or WHERE active = 1)`

in case of post e.g.: `WHERE published > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using `conditional aggregation and Join`

```
select s.id,s.type,question, answer, active from FROM `structs` s
inner join
(
select struct_id, max(case when name='question' then value end) as question,
max(case when name='answer' then value end) as answer,
max(case when name='active' then value end) as active
from struct_fields group by struct_id
)f ON f.struct_id = s.id WHERE s.type = 'faq'
```